# All eigenvalues of $A \in M_n(\mathbb R)$ are real , then are all eigenvalues of $A^2$ real ( and also non-negative)?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, linear-transformations

Let $A \in M_n(\mathbb R)$ has all its eigenvalues real

$1.$ Is it true that all the eigenvalues of $A^2$ are real and non-negative?

$2.$ If $k$ is an eigenvalue of $A^2$ then is one of $\pm\sqrt k$ an eigenvalue of $A$ ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\textbf{Hint:}$ Det$(A^2-\lambda I) =$ Det$(A+\sqrt{\lambda}I)$Det$(A-\sqrt{\lambda}I)$.

Comment: May I know the reason for the downvote?

Comment: @Soumyua I can't tell who and why downvoted your answer, yet one question follows: what if $\;\lambda<0\;$ ? Your "hint" shows that one of $\;\pm\sqrt\lambda\;$ is an eigenvalue of $\;A\;$, but these would be complex non-real values. Besides this, we know about the values of $\;A\;$, so what's your point beginning with $\;A^2-\lambda I\;$ ? Perhaps I missed something?

Comment: @Joanpemo, I think that's the required contradiction. If $\lambda$ were to be complex, then $A$ would have a complex eigenvalue. However it is given that $A$ has only real eigenvalues.

Comment: @SoumyaSinha : So you mean to say if $k \in \mathbb C$ is an eigenvalue of $A^2$ then one of the two values of $\sqrt k$ is an eigenvalue of $A$ and since all eigenvalues of $A$ are real so $k$ must be real and non-negative ... hmm that makes sense perhaps

Comment: Ok, I think I see now clearer: this addresses the *second* question the akser asks: if $\;\lambda\;$ is an eigenvalue of $\;A^2\;$ then $\;\pm\sqrt\lambda\;$ is an eigenvalue of $\;A\;$ , real or not, and etc. Yet the first part of the question was addressed, I think, by the other answer which also was downvoted, I'm not sure why, and that answer is now deleted.

Comment: @Joanpemo : I downvoted the other answer explaining my reason as it does not characterize what does the eigenvalues of $A^2$ actually looks like . But this answer seems to be okay

Answer (score 1):

Hint: $AX=\lambda X\Rightarrow A^2X=A(AX)=A(\lambda X)=\lambda(AX)=\lambda(\lambda X)=\lambda^2X$

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/41194/discussion-on-answer-by-la-belle-noiseuse-all-eigenvalues-of-a-in-m-n-mathbb).